# VS Code / Lua: handling of Cpp-directives

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I'm using C-preprocessor to get conditional-code, code-include and real constants in Lua. Unfortunately VS-Code / Lua gets confused about the `#`-directives in the lua code.

Is there a way to somehow exclude these lines from the parsing of the lua-extension?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using external tooling already I'd just replace the `#` with `--#` and preprocess it once more:

test.lua:

```lua
    --# if defined(TEST)
    print("test defined:", TEST)
    --# else
    print("test not defined")
    --# endif
```

```sh
❯ cat test.lua | sed -r 's:--#:#:g' | gcc -E -P -xc -  | luajit
test not defined

❯ cat test.lua | sed -r 's:--#:#:g' | gcc -E -P -DTEST=42 -xc -  | luajit
test defined:   42
```

It might be helpful to use the [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) extension and define the '#' to be highlighted.

[image]